# What is the equivalent of Scala's map case in Python

Tags: python, scala

In Scala, you could write expressions like

```
A.map{case (x, y) => (y, y)}
```

I was wondering, how we write the equivalent statement in Python?

Comment: What does this have to do with mapreduce and spark?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Scala, so I have to guess a bit.  This looks like you are mapping a function taking two arguments over a list of pairs, and replace each pair with two times the second element.  In Python, you would use a list comprehension for this purpose:

```
[(y, y) for x, y in A]
```

The Scala function probably uses pattern matching to assign the value of `x` and `y`.  Python doesn't have pattern matching, but in this simple case sequence unpacking achieves the same goal.